# Typescript: import library without npm - import external

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

I am trying to use `Chart.js` library in my project.
I want to import it externaly and not to instal the package by npm install.

Also about `@types/chart.js` I must install it from npm install or there is other option externally.
Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "external"?

Comment: ```<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>``` 

Something like that, import from a CDN URL and not install the package from npm

Comment: typescript isn't directly supported on browsers. So I doubt you can do that

Comment: Yeah , you would have to use your bundler, what are you using? Why does `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>` not work and why not use npm?